# TypeError: wrong argument (String)! (Expected kind of OpenSSL::Digest::Digest)

Tags: ruby, openssl

I have a problem with Ruby's openssl library.

Here is what I do:

In my Rails application, I start the "./script/console", then type:

> >>OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256','','')

gives me this error:

> TypeError: wrong argument (String)! (Expected kind of OpenSSL::Digest::Digest)
>         from (irb):15:in `hexdigest'
>         from (irb):15

I googled this error but couldn't get an answer on what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says you gave a string where an object of kind `OpenSSL::Digest::Digest` was expected.

So use `OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new` (which is an object of kind `OpenSSL::Digest::Digest` on account of `SHA256` being a subclass of `Digest`) instead of `'sha256'` (which is a string).